# How do I install Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: upgrade

I have downloaded the Ubuntu 14.04 ISO through Firefox, do I have to save it to a disk? Or how do I get it to just run? I have changed the repositories to `[...]old-release[...]` but I still can't get any update. When I run `/etc/apt/sources.list` I get a permission denied error.

Answer (score 0):

As Gregory pointed out, use either Unetbootin or [Universal USB Installer](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/) to create a live bootable USB drive. Then if you boot from this USB and select install,it will ask you whether to upgrade to 14.04 ( if indeed you are running versions < 14.04).

Comment: Universal USB Installer is the one to use in Windows 8 because UNetbootin doesn't support Windows 8 and Windows 10.

Comment: Really! I didn't know that. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I personally use Unetbootin and create a bootable USB drive to install my distros, And it gives me the ability to try it out and make sure everything works before I install.